# parsing json values with php from an array

Tags: php, json, parsing

I have an array and i am trying to decode and parse the json values, 
can't get it right.

Here's the info:

```
$send[0] :
Array ( [0] => {"message-count":"1","messages":[{"error-text":"Missing to param","status":"2"}]} ) 

var_dump(json_decode($v_send[0]));

/* output
json Dunmpobject(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["message-count"]=> string(1) "1" ["messages"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#2 (2) { ["error-text"]=> string(16) "Missing to param" ["status"]=> string(1) "2" } } } 
*/


var_dump(json_decode($v_send[0], true));

/* output
array(2) { ["message-count"]=> string(1) "1" ["messages"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["error-text"]=> string(16) "Missing to param" ["status"]=> string(1) "2" } } } 
*/

$json=json_decode($v_send[0]);

echo "Start:";
echo "<br/><br/>";
// To loop
if (!is_array($json)) die('...');
foreach ($json as $key=>$tts_result)
{
    echo $tts_result->callid;
    echo "<br/><br/>";
    echo $tts_result->to;
    echo "<br/><br/>";
    echo $tts_result->messages["status"];
    echo "<br/><br/>";
    echo $tts_result->error-text;
}
```

the echo in the loop gives empty result. anyone can help ?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$key->`?

Comment: @Fred No. @OP, have you tried using `print_r` to see how the array looks like before outputting it? Understanding the structure is 1/2 way there. If you get a NULL or an empty array, the issue is at the actual parsing or the response you get.

Comment: Yes, the first line is the array contents.

Answer (score 0):

`$json` is not an array, it's an object (of class `stdClass`).

If you want arrays, pass `true` as second argument of `json_decode`:

```
$json = json_decode($v_send[0], true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments,  tried, but get zero output. I want to retrieve each element values. more help ?